# Quiz Application returning duplicates

Tags: java, random, duplicates, set, hashset

I'm relatively new to programming , and I'm creating a quiz application. The problem is it keeps on repeating questions

```
Random random = new Random();
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
while (set.size() < 3) {
    set.add(random.nextInt(quizQuestions.size())); }
// three random QuizQuestion indexes. e.g., [2, 6, 9] which may represent: [run, cry, jump]
Integer[] answers = set.toArray(new Integer[set.size()]);
// indexes [0, 1 , 2] to randomly fetch the QuizQuestion indexes:
ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2));
//set the animation question and increment:
for (int index = 0; index < indexes.size(); index++){
quizAnswer = quizQuestions.get(answers[index]);}
```

Can someone please direct me to where I'm getting it wrong , and a solution with code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `nextInt` can return "duplicates" -- it's just a stream of random numbers.

Comment: And by the way your `indexes` array is unused, other than providing its size.

Answer (score 1):

Removing from a shuffled `List` is the way to go for something like this, so:

```
   int numQuestions = quizQuestions.size();
    List<Integer> randomQuestionIndexes = IntStream.range(0, numQuestions)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(randomQuestionIndexes);
    // Now *remove* n indexes at a time to ensure no repeat questions
```

Here's how to [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(int))

Comment: You don't need to remove them -- you can just use them from index 0 to size-1.

Comment: Removing them means that they can't be used again and therefore cause duplicates. It also keeps track of what has been used